# file upload not upload in folder codeigniter

Tags: php, file, codeigniter, file-upload

I have problem, my orig_name file upload is success upload in database but file not upload in my folder..

this my controller code

```
public function insert(){
        $this->model->register();
        $this->run_upload();
        redirect('Controling/daftar');
    }
    public function run_upload(){
        $config['upload_path'] = './upload/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|pdf';
        $config['max_size'] = '100000';
        $config['max_width'] = '3024';
        $config['max_heigth'] = '2024';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $datafoto=$this->upload->data();
            $nm_file = time().$datafoto['orig_name'];
            $this->load->model('model');
            $this->model->update_file($nm_file);
            copy('upload/'.$datafoto['orig_name'], 'upload/'.$nm_file);
    }
```

this my view code

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('Controling/insert', 'form="form"')?>
        <h2 class="">Register</h2>
        <label>Nim</label><input type="text" name="nim" class="form-control"><br />
        <label>Username</label><input type="text" name="username" class="form-control"><br />
        <label>Password</label><input type="password" name="password" class="form-control"><br />
        <label>Masukkan File</label>
        <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" class="form-control"><br />
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="register" value="Daftar">
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: Change `$config['upload_path'] = './upload/';` to `$config['upload_path'] = '../upload/';` and see.

Comment: its not working nana

Comment: For moving file to a folder. Are you using this line `copy('upload/'.$datafoto['orig_name'], 'upload/'.$nm_file);` ?

Comment: yes i think that is working, why ?

Comment: try this $config['upload_path'] = str_replace("\\","/",FCPATH).'upload/'; and set 777 to upload folder

Comment: i dont know what you mean set 777 to upload folder Aldo

Answer (score 0):

Inside the config/mimes.php add the missing file type you are going to uplaod, something like bellow.

```
'mpeg'  =>  array('video/mpeg', 'video/quicktime'),
'mpg'   =>  array('video/mpeg', 'video/quicktime'),
'mp4'   =>  array('video/mp4', 'video/quicktime'),
'mpe'   =>  array('video/mpeg', 'video/quicktime'),
'qt'    =>  'video/quicktime',
'mov'   =>  array('video/quicktime', 'video/mp4'),
'avi'   =>  array('video/avi', 'video/x-msvideo'),
```